# Mapping over a list of variables using quosures

Tags: r, purrr, quosure

Lets say I want to use `purrr::map` to create a list of models, each using a different variable as a predictor. I would imagine I could do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
myvars <- vars(cyl, disp, hp)
list_of_models <- map(myvars, function(x) lm(mpg ~ !!x, data = mtcars))
```

Can someone explain why this does not work?

The desired output is:

```
list(
lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars),
lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars),
lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to convert to string, create the formula with `reformulate` and pass it on to `lm`

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
out2 <- map(myvars, ~ {
       fmla <- reformulate(as_name(.x), 'mpg')
       lm1 <- lm(fmla, data = mtcars)
       lm1$call$formula <- fmla
       lm1 })
```

-output

```
out2
#[[1]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          cyl  
#     37.885       -2.876  


#[[2]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         disp  
#   29.59985     -0.04122  


#[[3]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           hp  
#   30.09886     -0.06823
```

-checking with the OP's output

```
out1 <- list(
     lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars),
      lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars),
      lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars))
setequal(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a different approach but easy to follow.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>% 
 select(cyl, disp, hp) %>% 
 map(~lm(mtcars$mpg ~ .x, data = mtcars))
```

Output

```
$`cyl`

Call:
 lm(formula = mtcars$mpg ~ .x, data = mtcars)

 Coefficients:
 (Intercept)           .x  
      37.885       -2.876  


$disp

Call:
lm(formula = mtcars$mpg ~ .x, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)           .x  
     29.59985     -0.04122  


$hp

Call:
lm(formula = mtcars$mpg ~ .x, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)           .x  
     30.09886     -0.06823
```

Hope this helps!